# Java Zip File Created With ByteArrayOutputStream is smaller than with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, zip, fileoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

The Zip file output from using ByteArrayOuputStream is smaller than that with FileOutputStream.

In Java I am creating a Zip file. Which opens successfully when I use FileOutputStream.

When switching the FileOutputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream I get a slightly smaller file, about 221 bytes. And this file won't open, but has the same contents as the other but missing 221 bytes.

The logic I use to construct the Zip file is the same in both cases. Therefore I will share the essential logic without the zip creation (let me know if you need this).

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
```

Then I create the Zip file, and then ...

```
        zipOS.flush();
        baos.flush();
        baos.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_BYTESTREAM_1.zip"));
        zipOS.close();
        baos.close();
```

I'm using the baos.writeTo() to bypass this to prove it's not the HTTP response but the ByteArrayOutputStream element thats an issue.

When using `baos.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_BYTESTREAM_1.zip"));`
I get a smaller file that doesn't open as a Zip.

This logic is in a java controller so that a link clicked on web page will down load the zip file without touching any file systems excepted the users.

Here is the code using FileOutputStream which works...

```
        FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_FILE.zip");
        zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
```

Aside from the the second code snippet isn't relevant as I would need to send the file created on the web server. But the point is, that Fileoutput stream with the same logic and ByteArrayOutputStream has a difference.

Comment: You should close the `zipOS` **before** getting the content of the `baos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final answer is as follows. Many thanks to the answer previously given.

Basically I needed to use the .finish() method of the ZipOuputStream. Everything else remained the same.

Pre zip creation code same as before

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
```

Post zip creation...

```
        zipOS.flush();
        zipOS.finish();
        baos.flush();
        documentBody = baos.toByteArray();
        zipOS.close();
        baos.close();
```

Then my HTTP response is

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "zip"));
    headers.setContentLength(documentBody.length);
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(documentBody);

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(resource);
```

This way I avoid the creation of a file which is nice.

Many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: It's helpful to me

Answer (score 4):

The following statement is wrong:

```
baos.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_BYTESTREAM_1.zip"));
```

The javadoc of [`writeTo(OutputStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) does not say anything about closing the `OutputStream`, which means it doesn't, so the last of the data is still sitting buffered in the un-closed, un-flushed `FileOutputStream`.

The correct way is:

```
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_BYTESTREAM_1.zip")) {
    baos.writeTo(out);
}
```

---

Also, a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) does not need to be closed or flushed. As the javadoc of [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close--) says it:

> Closing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect.

You will however need to call [`finish()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#finish--) on an [`ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) to complete the content. Since closing the zip stream automatically finishes it for you, the correct way to do this is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (ZipOutputStream zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
    // create the Zip file content here
}
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_BYTESTREAM_1.zip")) {
    baos.writeTo(out);
}
```

When writing directly to a file:

```
try (ZipOutputStream zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("TEST_AS_FILE.zip"))) {
    // create the Zip file content here
}
```

Consider adding a `BufferedOutputStream` for better performance.

Comment: Thanks , the only thing I needed to do was add the .finish() call on the zip output stream. Will share answeer below.